# Sending a 64 byte packet through serial port with C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb

I'm trying to send a command to the MCP2221 microchip using c# via the usb port. Said command is 64 bytes long and consists mostly of 0x00, except the first byte being 0xB0. I create a byte array, set said bytes, and write it using the serialport.write command.
After examining the sent bytes with an ellysis usb explorer, I notice that it sends the command in form of 16 byte long ACK signals, and with multiple hundred blocks of empty NAK signals of equal length inbetween.
What can I do the command properly in form of a single 64 byte package? The Serial Port using the default settings of a baudrate of 9600, no parity, and one stop bit, which the microchip should be fine with.
I would be very grateful with any form of assistance.

---

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: dont forget approve my answer friend​ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem before and it happen becase event run before recive the file completely so at the first  command inside event run Thread.Sleep(200)
so do what you want.
do it in 2 side is better

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your serial port is configured to use flow control (by default). And your controller probably does not support flow control, or is not configured to support it. If you don't want flow control, you can try to simply disable it:

```
port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it does seem quite reasonable. I'm afraid I have been sick with a strong fever since the 11th and haven't been able to leave my house, and dont have the hardware at hand to test it. I will come back to you with the results as soon as possible. Thank you kindly for your support.

Comment: Turns out that Handshake is disabled by default, which confuses me greatly